# Node.js: Remotely Submitting Forms

Tags: javascript, forms, node.js, express

I'm currently working on a sort of Web Proxy for Node.js, but I am having trouble with submitting forms, on most sites I am able to successfully submit a form but on some other sites I am not so fortunate. I can't pinpoint if there is anything I'm doing wrong.

Is there a possible better way of doing this?

Also, how would I be able to handle multipart forms using the Express.js bodyparser?

At the moment this is what I have in the way of form processing is this:

```
function proxy(req, res,request)
{ 

var sess = req.session;

var onUrl_Parse = function(url){
        var  Uri= new URI.URI(url);//Parses incoming url
            var options = {
                uri: url,
                method: req.method
            }

                options.headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows  NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0", "Cookie":req.session.cook};



        if(req.body) //If x-www-form-urlencoded is posted.
        {
            var options = {
                uri: url,
                method: req.method,
                body: req.rawBody
            }
                options.headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows  NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0", "Cookie":req.session.cook, "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"};
        }


    onRequestOptions(options, url);
}

,onRequestOptions = function(options, url)
{       
    request(options, function(error, response, body)
    {       
            if(!error){
                    if(response.headers['set-cookie'])
                        req.session.cook=response.headers['set-cookie'];
                Proxy_Parser.Parser(body, url, async, onParse);// Parses returned html return displayable content
            }

    });
}

,onParse = function(HTML_BODY)
    {
        if(HTML_BODY=="")
            res.end();
        res.write(HTML_BODY);
        res.end();
        console.log("DONEEEEE");
    }   



Url_Parser.Url(req, URI, onUrl_Parse);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable is a anyway recommended !!

Comment: I have no clue why my answer has been down voted. It would be great if the reason is mentioned so that I don't repeat the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). All the hard work is done for you and you can just define the routes you want to proxy and put in some handlers for the custom response info.

Comment: Is this able to handle requests to external websites?
If so are there any examples?

Comment: Yes, the second sample *Setup a stand-alone proxy server with custom server logic* does that. Just change the port and URL for wherever you are point it.